# Yii many_many condition not working

Tags: php, yii, many-to-many

I have a many_many relation between Product and Interest. I'm trying to select 5 products that are attributed to a particular interest. The code I have so far isn't working and I can't find the route cause.

My relations:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'interests'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Interest', 'interest_product_assignment(product_id,interest_id)'),
```

My function within the Product model used to return the products:

```
public function getProducts($id){
    return $products = Product::model()->with('interests')->find(
        array(
            'condition' => "interests.interest_id = $id",
            'limit' => 5
        )
    );
}
```

When I use the function an error shows:

```
"Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'interests.interest_id' "
```

The query that is run doesn't even attempt to join the two tables.

Can anyone spot the cause of this issue? I susepect this is elementary, but I can't see it.

Comment: Every syntax I've used to try writing the function getProducts as given the same error, which leads me to believe there's something wrong with the way I've set my relation up.

Comment: Is there a model for interests? What's it called?

Comment: Hi Mark, the model for interests is Interest. The above code is written in the Product model.